# Snowflake View: Max LOB size exceeded error while trying to join data from another table

Tags: sql, view, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am quite new to snowflake and I have this view that left joins a large sub table with the main table.
I need an array object in the process.
But I am getting

**"Max LOB size exceeded (16777216) error"** ,

while trying to query the view.

Is there someway I can solve this ?

```
create or replace view SAMPLE_DB.SAMPLE_SCHEMA.V_VIEW as
  select
  cata.cat_key, sec.CAT_DATA
  from SAMPLE_DB.SAMPLE_SCHEMA.SAMPLE_ITEM  cata 

left join (select sec.cat_key,
              array_agg(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
                   'one_num', sec.one_num,
                   'two_num', sec.two_num)) CAT_DATA
                   from SAMPLE_DB.SAMPLE_SCHEMA.SEC_TABLE sec
                   group by sec.cat_key) pol on (cata.cat_key = sec.cat_key) ;
```

Comment: I suspect one of these rows has too much data (~16MB). Can you repeat the experiment leaving the extra heavy rows out?

Comment: OBJECT_CONSTRUCT returns an OBJECT, which is a semi-structured data types, and these are limited to 16MB, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#data-types)

Comment: Why do you want an array larger than 16 MB?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the answer in the snowflake community   [link](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r00009labjnCAA/max-lob-size-16777216-exceeded-actual-size-of-parsed-column-is-28868588when-trying-to-run-a-select-query-on-large-data-set-with-the-group-by-aggregate)

```
 group by & aggregate on key where there might be no data.
```